# How to properly read csv with dates and omitted leading zeros in pandas?

Tags: python, date, datetime, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a csv/txt file with the following structure:

```
caseid   eventdate     constype  consid  employid  delta
4044     13/11/1996    9         2301    3044      0
```

This is what I know already:

1. `caseid`, `consid` and  `employid` are 8 digit strings (with leading zeros that will not appear in the text file)
2. `eventdate` is a dd/mm/yyyy date
3. `costype` is a string
4. `delta` is a float

Now, what is the pandas syntax to properly read this csv/text so all columns are appropriately typed?

I am using this:

```
pd.read_csv(path, 
            types = {'caseid': np.char,
                     'eventdate': np.datetime64,
                     'constype': np.char,
                     'consid': np.char,
                     'employid': np.char,
                     'delta': np.float16})
```

But this cannot take care of dates and leading zeros - any thoughts/suggestions/help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me, you need to pass a dict as a param to `dtype`, the types should be types that are understood, I'd pass `str` instead of `char`, also if you pass param `parse_dates=[1]` instead of trying to specify it in the dtypes then pandas built in date parser parses the date string just fine.

To pad the zeroes you can define a function to pad the zeroes and pass this to the param `converters` passing a dict of the columns and the name of the function, for those columns it's not necessary to pass the dtype as it'll be inferred by the fact it will be converted to a `str` by `padZeros`:

```
def padZeros(x):
    return str(x).zfill(8)

df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\s+', dtype = {'constype': str,
                     'delta': np.float16}, parse_dates=[1],
                     converters={'caseid':padZeros,
                                 'consid':padZeros,
                                 'employid':padZeros})
```

output from `df.info()`:

```
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 6 columns):
caseid       1 non-null object
eventdate    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
constype     1 non-null object
consid       1 non-null object
employid     1 non-null object
delta        1 non-null float16
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float16(1), object(4)
memory usage: 50.0+ bytes
None

In [19]:

df
Out[19]:
     caseid  eventdate constype    consid  employid  delta
0  00004044 1996-11-13        9  00002301  00003044      0
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine - thanks Ed! I added the date parser too (apparently, the auto-parser doesn't deal well with missing dates and hence returns string: `parse_dates = lambda x: date(2020, 1, 1) if x is np.nan else datetime.strptime(str(x),'%d/%m/%Y')`